# Python multiprocessing No file descriptors available error inside docker alpine

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-multiprocessing, alpine-linux

`OSError: [Errno 24] No file descriptors available` while creating multiprocessing queue. It only occurs when using alpine image (`FROM python:alpine3.19`) normal image (`FROM python`) works fine. I have tried incressing ulimit.
Default docker setting:

```
"default-ulimits": {
    "nofile": {
      "Hard": 4096,
      "Name": "nofile",
      "Soft": 4096
    },
    "nproc": {
      "Hard": 4096,
      "Name": "nproc",
      "Soft": 4096
    }
  }
```

And also during 'run' command see below. Ulimit setting seems to work fine (it is visible in `/proc/1/limits`). Is there some other limit that I am not aware of?

### Steps to reproduce:

Dockerfile:

```
# FROM python
FROM python:alpine3.19
WORKDIR test
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "test.py"]
```

test.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queues = []
    print((subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/proc/1/limits'])).decode())
    for i in range(1000):
        print(f"Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. {i} ", end="")
        queues.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
        print("ok")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("all ok")
```

(`docker build -t test .`)

### Output (`FROM python`):

- Test low nofile limit
- works as expected
- hitting limit at about 128/2 queues

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit nofile=128 test

Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. 62 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    queues.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._reader, self._writer = connection.Pipe(duplex=False)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 543, in Pipe
    fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
               ^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

- Test high nofile limit
- works beautifully

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit nofile=4096 test

Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. 998 ok
Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. 999 ok
all ok
```

### Output (`FROM python:alpine3.19`):

- Test low nofile limit
- works as expected
- hitting limit at about 128/2 queues

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit nofile=128 test

Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. 62 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    queues.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._reader, self._writer = connection.Pipe(duplex=False)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 543, in Pipe
    fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
               ^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 24] No file descriptors available
```

- Test high nofile limit
- Also fails
- What's wrong here?

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit nofile=4096 test

Appending multiprocessing.Queue() n. 85 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    queues.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._wlock = ctx.Lock()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 169, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 24] No file descriptors available
```

Edit:

- I am running Docker Engine v24.0.7 from Windows 11
- It behaves the same on Centos 8 (Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b)
- I also tried:
- multiprocessing.Value(c_int, 0) -> Fails at 256. iteration.
- multiprocessing.Lock() -> Fails at 256. iteration.
- multiprocessing.Semaphore(1) -> Fails at 256. iteration.
- threading.Semaphore(1) -> Does **not** fail.
- (multiprocessing.Pipe()) -> Does **not** fail.
- multiprocessing.SimpleQueue() -> Fails at 128. iteration.
- multiprocessing.Condition() -> Fails at 64. iteration.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I can reproduce this failure, and what's more a simple test that only calls open() can successfully open files up to the expected limit so the problem is **not** simply that the file limit isn't being respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is seems related to alpine linux using musl, while debian uses glibc: It is not actually file descriptors lacking, but [POSIX-`sem_open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) can raise `EMFILE` too if the limit of semaphores is exceeded.

As all listed multiprocessing-classes use semaphores internally, this limit is eventually reached (earlier for classes using multiple semaphores).

The limit is given as [`SEM_NSEMS_MAX`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/include/limits.h#n70) and specified as 256. The code actually raising `EMFILE` is in [`sem_open`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/sem_open.c#n63).

Huge thanks to @psykose from #musl for pointing this out to someone new to C like me.

**So why is it working on glibc / debian then?**

Generally, the glibc-implementation of `sem_open` does not allow for `EMFILE` to happen, so the issue simply cannot occur using glibc (unless of course system resources are exhausted). Some further information is available on the [libc-help mailinglist](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-help/2012-02/msg00001.html).

While I [posted](https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2024/01/08/1) about the problem on the musl-mailinglist, I really do not know how much work a change would be and what the priority would be. So for the moment, the most sensible way is probably to use a different distribution which is using glibc for now.

Edit: Another solution would of course be python changing the semaphore-mechanism to in-memory-semaphores, if this is possible. I added a discussion point at [the Python Discourse](https://discuss.python.org/t/why-is-cpython-multiprocessing-using-named-semaphores/42735).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue and actual effort to solve underlaying problem.